# Paypal Adaptive Payments SDK integration in Yii 1.1.x

Tags: php, yii, paypal

I am trying to integrate Paypal Adaptive Payments SDK in Yii 1.1.x framework.

I installed composer and created a composer.json file with the following contents.

```
{
    "name": "me/myApp",
    "require": {
        "paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php":"3.8.*"
    }
}
```

and I run `composer update`.
I have updated the `Configuration.php`. After I require `PPBootStrap.php` in my application

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.pp.*', true);
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
require_once('PPBootStrap.php');
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

after I create the receiver

```
$receiver = array();
$receiver[0] = new Receiver();
```

and I get the error:

```
include(Receiver.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I integrated [Angelleye](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) following the same logic with no problems (I am able to make payments). But I want to use the official sdk from PayPal.

I am not sure why the class Receiver is not being loaded. Any information and/or guidance on how to solve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ya know, even PayPal integration managers have been using and recommending my library.  You said yourself, it works nice and easy while PayPal's "official" SDK is confusing and tough to work with.  I am an official PayPal partner.  I would really recommend just sticking with mine.  :)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, most likely I will stick to Angelleye library

Comment: Which full path of your Receiver.php file?

Comment: protected\vendor\paypal\adaptivepayments-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Types\AP\Receiver.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try to require composer autoloader without unregistering yii autoloader.
Add this line for example to the `index.php` before running application:

```
...
require(__DIR__ . '/protected/vendor/autoload.php');
Yii::createWebApplication($configFile)->run();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried and I get the same error: include(Receiver.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory